# Floating labels in Telerik winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I need floating labels in `RadTextBox` and `RadDropDownList` using telerik winforms.

Telerik has this feature implemented in their [Floating Labels in kendo.react](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dropdowns/floating-labels/#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20the%20floating%20label%20functionality%2C%20pass%20a,and%20style%20them%20with%20the%20KendoReact%20Material%20theme.) library for various controls.

However I'm using `Telerik UI for Winforms R2 2020` which does not support this. In `R2 2021` Telerik has added support only for floating labels [Floating Labels](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/editors/textbox/programming-radtextbox#embedded-labels) in `RadTextBox/RadTextBoxControl` but not for `RadDropDownList`. I can't upgrade to `R2 2021`.

I need some customization tips to implement floating labels in both `RadTextBox` and `RadDropDown` using `Telerik Winforms`.

Regards,
Lakshman

Answer (score 0):

Lakshman,

As of R2 2021 RadTextBox and RadTextBoxControl support embedded labels. If you need to use this functionality in your Telerik WinForms project, feel free to upgrade: https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/winforms/release-history/ui-for-winforms-r2-2021-(version-2021-2-511) Since RadDropDownList internally hosts a textbox, this functionality is available for RadDropDownList as well:

[image]

The embedded label shows text in the text box field, usually to indicate what text the user should enter. When the text box gets focused, the embedded label will go up, so the user can type in the text box field. The ShowEmbeddedLabel property controls whether the embedded label is shown. You can set the desired text by using the EmbeddedLabelText property. This feature is not available in older than R2 2021 versions. Hence, in order to benefit the new improvements in the textbox editors, it is necessary to upgrade to at least this version.